# How to use loop in splinter and lettuce test?

Tags: testing, lettuce, splinter

I want to ask whether it is possible to use for-loop or while-loop together with splinter and lettuce BBD test.

One of my scenario is that: I want to loop a table and change each entry status until all entries status are changed. I can change one entry status and go back to the table. How can I do it in a loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Need more detail. 
Splinter code is Python code - so all of Python's looping constructs are available.

If you are able to read your table in as a list, then just loop over the list using a for loop, and make the changes you want.

Hope this helps.